# Handling Facebook and Twitter users as one user on website

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, twitter, oauth-2.0

On my site i gave two options for user to login FB and Twitter, I successfully got user info from both APi's, now I want to handle facebook and twitter users in my MySQL database as one user.

For example : If someone registers with his FB profile and later if same user logged in with his Twitter account .I want to identify the user then.

Can it be possible? Any how?

Comment: I think you can do this only if they have the same email address. Otherwise, they don't really have common fields :) (except facebook having a twitter field or the other way around)

Comment: you could try storing cookies to recognize if a user has already been on your site with a different account

Comment: Hi Vlad Preda, Thks for quick response, but 'email' is not in permissions scope (i dont need email from user) .. have to find other way than this.

Comment: @cppanda hmm cookies.. can try it out..not sure it will be reilable or not. thx

Answer (score 0):

if the user has used the same email address for facebook and twitter accounts, then if you have used the oauth settings to have carnal access to the facebook and twitter accounts then you could pick this out and compare them, but it's terrible practice.

on your own app do you ask for additional information? could you put in a branch that if a user is entering in data that you already have then you ask them if they are the same user? possibly checked by password?

Could you supply more information if i have misunderstood?

Margaret

Comment: Hello Margaret,

I am not asking for 'email' to user..i dont need, Just Basic info i am fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter and Facebook accounts are not generally linked, there is no way for you to find out automatically if they belong together. Even the email address could be misleading.

But is this even necessary? I would assume that a user that decides to log into your site via Facebook will always use Facebook. When they decide to user their Twitter login instead, they will *expect* to have a separate account.

You could give users the ability to "link" their accounts. When they have logged in via Facebook, provide a button "Add Twitter account" and vice versa. Then you can be sure that the person owns both accounts. This could even work when a user has multiple Facebook or Twitter accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you would need to have a facebook field and a twitter field in the user table, and you would need to provide the user with the means of associating their existing account with their twitter / facebook account (whichever they weren't already using).

Personally I would favour having a user table which requires neither facebook nor twitter, but can use both. That we, Google+ people can use your site without being offended.